# How an argument is passed in NODE js function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have got a sample code from internet as

```
const net = require('net');  
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {  
  socket.end('goodbye\n');  
}).on('error', function(err) {  
  // handle errors here  
  throw err;  
});  
// grab a random port.  
server.listen(function() {  
  address = server.address();  
  console.log('opened server on %j', address);  
});
```

Here there is a piece of code as function(socket), how socket is defined, how this function works. Can anyone explain it.

Comment: it's a callback that is called by the net.createServer function which passes the socket as the first argument to this callback

Comment: Something like `net.createServer = function(callback) { var socket = /*create socket*/; callback(socket); };`. Lets simplify this: If you have a function `function foo(bar) { }`, how does calling and passing an argument work? Just like that: `foo(42)`. `bar` will have the value `42`. To learn more about functions, have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html.

Answer (score 1):

Now there, in JS you can assign anonymous functions to variables just like this:

```
var sum = function(a, b) { return a + b; };
```

You can call that

```
var first_argument = 1
var second_argument = 3
var result = sum(first_argument, second_argument)
```

But if you may pass variables to functions, and assign functions to variables. Could you pass functions to functions?

```
var binary_op = function(a, b, op) {
    return op(a, b);
}
binary_op(1, 2, sum);
```

Well, of course you can. In fact, you could do

```
binary_op(1, 2, function(a, b) { return a - b; });
```

Which would make binary_op call this anonymous function and ultimately return -1.